# Laravel 8 migration: DB:unprepared is not working on shared hosting server

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-migrations

My migrations worked as expected on the local server, but when I tried to deploy my project on the live shared hosting server and after using `php artisan migrate`, I got the below error.

> ```
> at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:692 
> 688▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
> 689▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
> 690▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
> 691▕         catch (Exception $e) {
> ➜ 692▕             throw new QueryException(
> 693▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
> 694▕             );
> 695▕         }
> 696▕     }
>
>   +7 vendor frames
>   8   database/migrations/2021_08_03_215015_create_user_turning_functions_table.php:14
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic("unprepared")
>
>   +21 vendor frames
>   30  artisan:37
> Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
> ```
>
> Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))

**Migration:**

```
public function up()
{
    DB::unprepared("
            CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `get_classes`(subjects VARCHAR(140))
            RETURNS varchar(200)
            BEGIN
            DECLARE classes VARCHAR(48);
            SET classes='something here';
            RETURN classes;
        END");
}

public function down()
{
    DB::unprepared('DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS get_classes');
}
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong here or what I have to do in such a case?

Comment: Are the database settings the same? does the DB user have the rights to create functions?

Comment: yes all other migration worked just function and view migration aren't working because it has `DB::unprepared("")`

Comment: Check in `app/database.php` and set ` 'strict'=>false ` and try again

Comment: @HardikSisodia
Do local server and hosting server have the same version?

Comment: @ThânLƯƠNG Are you asking about the php version? yes it's same

Comment: Can you provide more error details? You've redacted and possibly missed a lot of the error message and stack trace. What comes before `at vendor/laravel/framework/src...`?

Comment: Can you share you `.env` file?

Comment: That is not the exception message. Check your logs and share the exact log message here for help.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-an-unprepared-statement This link says that DB::unprepared('') will not bind values. The exception seems to be related to binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be off base, but I will give you the answer that, if true, you don't want to hear.

You mentioned shared hosting, and once I saw your code it really stuck out for me as I have worked in the hosting industry for some time. Typically, shared hosting providers do not allow you to use stored procedures/functions at all. I have not met one that does allow it.

This is just something typically not available on shared hosting providers and would require a VPS or dedicated server.

I hope my answer is wrong and they do allow it and you can solve your issue, however you should simply ask your provider in a live chat (if possible) if they allow stored procedures. There is a strong chance that they do not.